# Excel - Find if worker has worked certain OT if weekday and or Sunday

Tags: excel, sum, product, countif

I have a worksheet with days running along the columns, within each day there are different hourly categories, 130%, 150%, 200% and 215% etc, there are other categories within each day, but these are not to be included. (Can't post Image as new, can email?)

If a worker works over 3.5 hours in any of these categories they get an extra lunch, except on Sunday's where they must work 4 hours.

I've been using countif's to check each day over 3.5, and another column for Sunday's.

The weekday and Sunday can be combined into the same column as the lunch price is still the same, just number of working hours different.

The main problem is I have to adjust the countif's every month, I want something that will look at days of the week and/or sunday's and check without adjusting every month.

Have been trying to get my head around sumproduct with countif!

Any help, very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not mentioned what is where this might take some adjustment, but may get you started:

```
=IF(SUM(B3:G3)>=IF(WEEKDAY(B$1)=1,4,3.5),"lunch","no lunch")
```